# Excel AND statement with 3 conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this code in cell O2 and its working.

```
 =IF(OR(AND(M2=0;N2=0;I2>14);AND(N2<0,05;I2>14);AND(I2>14;N2<0,05););H2;"")
```

I want this additional condition. O2 should be also empty if L2 is greater than 0.
Adding a 3rd condition to the AND statements didnt work.

[image]

Comment: `=IF(OR(AND(M2=0;N2=0;I2>14);AND(N2<0,05;I2>14);AND(I2>14;N2<0,05);O2<=0);H2;"")`?  This will check if O2 is less than or equal to 0 and if so, return `H2` value, otherwise blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had an issue adding the statement to the `AND` for some reason. You could nest your equation inside another `IF` statement like so

`O2 = IF(L2 > 0; ""; x)`

where `x` = your current equation