# Excel Formula & Multiple IF conditions

Tags: excel-formula

I have three conditions that I want to write a formula

If cell a has value but cell b is marked notfound then the formula should retund likematch

If cell b is marked not found and cell b has some value, then the formula should return exactmatch
if both cell a and b have values, then it should return both. [image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried already.

Comment: Look around here - you should be able to edit this answer to your needs : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51866133/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple nested **If-Statement.**

Assuming your data starts at `A1`, paste the following in `C1`:

```
=If(And($A1<>"notfound",$B1="notfound"), "exactmatch", If(And($A1="notfound", $B1<>"notfound"), "likematch", If(And($A1<>"notfound",$B1<>"notfound"), "both")))
```

[image]